# Выборка из нескольких таблиц mysql на php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Привет всем! :-)

Я хочу сделать выбор из нескольких таблиц одновременно по строке 'namber' (кол-во таблиц 22, в каждой таблице по 4 колонки (id, namber, name, text).

Я решил сделать запрос `UNION`,  но не знаю корректно ли так делать запрос или есть другой более удобный и быстрый способ?

```
$namber = $_GET['namber']; 

require 'lib/connect.php';

$strSQL = "

SELECT * FROM `g_fight` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_drive` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_strategy` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_arcade` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION   
SELECT * FROM `g_azart` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_cart` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_classical` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_headcrash` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_history` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_interesting` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_kids` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_kidsschook` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_line` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_logical` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_pazzle` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_shoot` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_snake` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_spaceship` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_sport` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_walking` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_tetris` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_rolier` WHERE namber='$namber'
UNION
SELECT * FROM `g_ontable` WHERE namber='$namber'";

$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

    $str = "".$row['name']."";
    $NAME = str_replace(" ","",$str);

    $gtype="Игра";// тип (для закладки)

    $text="".$row['text']."";//описание


    mysql_close();
}
```

Comment: замените `union` на `union all` он быстрее. А так, у вас походу нет другого выхода с такой структурой БД. Более привильным решением было бы сделать одну общую таблицу, возможно с колонкой "тип игры". Хотя это больше похоже на жанры игр и у одной игры их может быть несколько. тогда напрашивается таблица игр, таблица жанров и связующая id_игры-id_жанра

Comment: Спасибо union all правда быстрее работает:-)

Comment: @Даниил пока с этим совсем не утопли, лучше сделайте как советует Mike. Ибо то, что написано — неправильно. Про нормальные формы почитайте, как связать таблицы и т.д.

Comment: Если еще не поздно (не очень много кода написано) подумайте все таки о изменении структуры БД. Сопровождать такое - это ад. А если новый жанр добавить - создавать новую таблицу и править _все_ скрипты. да и скорость с одной таблицей была бы больше.

Comment: И вместо звёзд везде явно перечисляйте поля. А то первое же ALTER TABLE подарит незабываемые ощущения..

Comment: @Akina явное перечисление полей в таком запросе уже подарит их)) не говорю что это не нужно делать....но это да....если вдруг по какой-то причине они будут различаться)

Comment: _явное перечисление полей в таком запросе уже подарит их_ Ой, да ладно! тоже мне незабывашка... поля  ж стопудово одноимённые, так что достаточно тупого поиска и замены в любом редактёре - а хоть бы и в блокноте..

Comment: @Akina я ж оговорочку внес: *если вдруг по какой-то причине они будут различаться*. ;-)  Но в любом случае это все не правильно что в вопросе)

Comment: _в любом случае это все не правильно что в вопросе_ Что да то да... а с другой стороны - если автору похрен, просто UNION или UNION ALL, хоть они и разный результат дают, то что ему такими мелочами надоедать, как какая-то там мифическая нормализация?

Comment: Под каждый тип игры своя таблица? Жесть просто...